# Prove that for any sets $A, B, C, D$, we have $(A × B) \setminus (C × D) = [A × (B \setminus D)] ∪ [(A \setminus C) × B]$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I've actually already attempted to prove this but when I checked the answer I saw that they did it by cases for the 1st part, which I didn't do. Is my proof (image attached below) incorrect? Could someone tell me why if so?

[Picture of my proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOSAx.png)

Thanks so much for any help!
-NL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems, most of which may just be typos, but there’s nothing wrong with your basic approach.

At the beginning of the first part of the proof you write:

> Suppose $(x,y)$ arbitrary such that $(A\times B)\setminus(C\times D)$.

Since $(A\times B)\setminus(C\times D)$ is just a set, not an assertion, this doesn’t make sense; it’s akin to saying ‘Let $x$ arbitrary be such that $\sqrt{a}$’. What you want is to let $\langle x,y\rangle\in (A\times B)\setminus(C\times D)$ be arbitrary. The rest of that part of the proof is fine until you get to the conclusion: for the second alternative you want

> $x\in A$ and $y\in B\setminus D$,

not

> $x\in B\setminus D$ and $y\in A$.

You have the same problem at the beginning of the second half that you at the beginning of the first half. What you mean is

> Let $\langle x,y\rangle$ be an arbitrary element of $\big[A\times(B\setminus D)\big]\cup\big[(A\setminus C)\times B\big]$.

You should then make it clear that each statement in the chain that follows implies the next, either verbally, or as you did with the implication arrows in the first part. The steps themselves are fine up to

$$(x\in A\land y\in B\land \color{red}x\notin D)\lor(x\in A\land x\notin C\land y\in B)\;,$$

which has a typo: you meant

$$(x\in A\land y\in B\land \color{red}y\notin D)\lor(x\in A\land x\notin C\land y\in B)\;.$$

Now you want to use one of the distributive laws to factor out $x\in A\land y\in B$, which is fine, but you did it incorrectly, even allowing for the previous typo: you should get

$$(x\in A\land y\in B)\color{red}\land(y\notin D\color{red}\lor x\notin C)\;.\tag{1}$$

Now apply one of the De Morgan laws to the second parenthesis to see that $(1)$ is equivalent to

$$(x\in A\land y\in B)\land\neg(x\in C\land y\in D)$$

and hence to

$$\langle x,y\rangle\in A\times B\land\langle x,y\rangle\notin C\times D\;,$$

i.e., to

$$\langle x,y\rangle\in(A\times B)\setminus(C\times D)\;.$$

Comment: Wow thank you so so much! I know we're not supposed to just say thanks, but this was super easy to follow. Thanks for spending the time to point out all my mistakes, it appears that I seem to misplace my x's and y's quite a bit. I hope you have a great day!

Comment: @NookLines: You’re welcome!